# Small amount of unwanted data going to iCloud

Tags: iphone, icloud

I don't want anything to be backed up to iCloud. However, my data cannot be recreated, so I need to place it in my application's documents directory. For each file, I did the standard:

```
    - (BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL
{
    if (&NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey == nil) { // iOS <= 5.0.1
        const char* filePath = [[URL path] fileSystemRepresentation];

        const char* attrName = "com.apple.MobileBackup";
        u_int8_t attrValue = 1;

        int result = setxattr(filePath, attrName, &attrValue, sizeof(attrValue), 0, 0);
        return result == 0;
    } else { // iOS >= 5.1
        return [URL setResourceValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error:nil];
    }
}
```

I have 5mB of data in there. But my app is still registering 0.2kB in iCloud (Through settings->iCLoud->Manage Storage). So, just to be sure, I did this:

```
-(void)resetBackupAttributes {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *fileListAct = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];
    for (NSString *path in fileListAct) {
        [self addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
    }

    NSArray *paths2 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *cacheDirectory = [paths2 objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *fileListCache = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:cacheDirectory error:nil];
    for (NSString *path in fileListCache) {
        [self addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
    }
    NSArray *paths3 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSPreferencePanesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *preferencesDirectory = [paths3 objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *fileListPref = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:preferencesDirectory error:nil];
    for (NSString *path in fileListPref) {
        [self addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
    }
}
```

It still has 0.2kB! Is there something I am missing? Does a small amount of data gets backed up regardless... like a directory tree or something? What I really want to know is, will this 0.2kB get me rejected for not following the data storage guidelines?

Comment: When I enable iCloud sync in [Tweetbot](http://tapbots.com/software/tweetbot/) then look in Settings > iCloud > Storage & Backup > Manage Storage, Tweetbot does not even show up. Maybe it takes a while before it starts showing up in the Settings? Or maybe its a bug? I am not posting this as an answer as I am not 100% sure and it might be a Tweetbot bug.

Comment: No, mine has been updated. It will take a few minutes for iCloud to update in my experiece.

Comment: Are you generating a file outside Documents directory (ex Library ..) or some other library which isn't the Cache directory ?

Comment: In my cache folder, I have my cache.db, which is 500kB, so that isn't what is popping up. In my preferences, I have the application plist file; peoplepicker.plist; .glocalPreferences.plist. All of my plist files are 4kB. So, those aren't them either. Those are all the files I have.

Comment: is it possible that your apps default plist gets backed up in the cloud? - BUT you could hook up a proxy between your iOS (simulator) and the internet. Just catch all outgoing data and see whats actually get transmitted ;). e.g. SquidMan

Comment: After spending a lot of time banging my head on this, I do believe it is the plist that is being backed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so I will put my comment into an answer:

> is it possible that your apps default plist gets backed up in the
>   cloud? - BUT you could hook up a proxy between your iOS (simulator)
>   and the internet. Just catch all outgoing data and see whats actually
>   get transmitted ;). e.g. SquidMan

here's the link to [SquidMan](http://squidman.net/squidman/index.html) just in case …
As you said you think its the plist too. You can verify that by setting a key with some junk data and see if the total amount rises. ;)

Comment: Can you please explain the solution here? I have the same issue and I found out that saving some date with NSUserDefaults cause small amount of data being added to cloud storage.

Comment: the plist gets synced to iCloud because the App thinks that it has to save some settings for further uses. `NSUserDefaults` normally copies the bundle plist to documents folder I think. You can try to create the plist in Caches dir and register this path with `NSUserDefaults` or just read the plist directly with `arrayWithContentsOfFile:` / `dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:`

Comment: How about if i just tag this directory as non-backupable?

Comment: I mean entire /NSPreferencePanesDirectory  to make sure It would not get backup by iCloud?

Comment: didn't work, I had to remove the assert( assert([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: [URL path]]);) from the addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL() though but still didn't work. If I  tag entire /Library(NSLibraryDirectory) it will WORK

Comment: The only thing I found different is I have bunch of hidden files in /Document directory. Not sure for calling addSkipBackupAttribute for those files should be modify the method? cause the calling method on them doesn't help to reduce the storage size(around 1KB) that I have